# How do you make a file stay permanently on heroku after the first push?

Tags: git, laravel, heroku, push

I am working on a Laravel project. I am using Heroku to host the the app for testing.

When I am working offline, I want to use a particular set of config in the **.env** file and when I am pushing to heroku I want use another set of config that corresponds to the heroku environment. The problem is that I don't want to create another branch for the online and the offline because I would have to merge anytime I make changes to one branch. How can I make the .env on heroku stay on heroku permanently regardless of the push I make to it?

Comment: Never push .env file to the repository. On the Heroku you add environment variables in a "Settings" tab under the "Config Variables" section.

Comment: That means I will manually add the keys in .env file to the config vars in heroku and all will be set

Comment: Right. Don't forget to add .env to the .gitignore file

Comment: I wont .Thank you very much